# using google geoloccation without google map

Tags: geolocation

I am using Google geoloc to verify and normalize addresses determine places within a specific radius. However, google documentation states that the Google Maps Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google Map.
I want to know if this applies to me since I am not displaying this data on the client side

Comment: Are you ok with alternatives?

Comment: There is a built in function http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Thank you arodebaugh, but how will I be able to use this service to get thousands of responses based on records in a database (sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Google Geocoder is not optimal for all/many situations, particularly those requiring massive amounts of geocoding for a preset dataset. The comprehensive list of alternative APIs could be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/NonGoogleGeocoders).

Even though [Google Maps Geocoding API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) documentation says:

> The Google Maps Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a
>   Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is
>   prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms > of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10).

it is technically doable to utilize Maps Geocoding API *without* displaying results on map as demonstrated below:

```js
function initMap() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder);
    });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = results[0].geometry.location.toString();
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}

#panel {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
        <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
        <div id="result"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```